# React-native :app:bundleReleaseSourceMapUpload FAILED

Tags: android, react-native

I'm coded a app with use react-native and I want export release apk. For this, i running this commands ;

1 - react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/

2 - cd android

3 - ./gradlew clean

4 - ./gradlew assembleDebug ( this step is successful)

5 - ./gradlew assembleRelease

After the 5. step, i'm getting an error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseSourceMapUpload'.

  > A problem occurred starting process 'command '/bin/sh''

My react-native & react versions;
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-native": "0.61.5",

I search this error but don't find any solution. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check SDK platforms and tools on Android Studio? Something must be missing there.

Answer (score 0):

I use a npm package, but it's currently beta. I uninstall this package and app is works.